# How to find common emitter current gain (beta) from graph

Tags: transistors, bjt, common-emitter

I am trying to find the common emitter current gain of a bjt transistor I made on ltspice, and I need to use the below graph to find it, but Im not sure how to interpret the graph to find it. Should I find the rms current of Ic and Ib and then just use that in the equation, Beta = Ic/Ib ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take the positive and negative peak values of both (peak-to-peak or Vp-p), subtract the negative value from the positive to get the actual signal Vp-p value for ic and ib, and then divide the ic by the ib to get the gain.
 I have tried 3 different approaches and for the one using a peak value approach I got the gain of about 194, with the method above I got about 190, and with another method I got 174 (most likely wrong).
 Either way, the scale on the right of the middle graph seems to be the gain, and the blue line is representing it because you have Ic(Q1)/Ib(Q1) in blue.
 However, this seems to be the DC gain which takes into account the quiescent current as well, showing the instantaneous DC voltage, and that's why it is a changing value.
 So, the approach of taking the **difference** between the positive and negative peaks will give you only the peak-to-peak value of the AC signal without the DC to skew the results (more accurate, and you get a single amplification value instead of a changing one).

Comment: as a side note, using peak-to-peak, peak or rms values all give the same result if the waveshape is sinusoidal without appreciable distortion. I get about 222 for the dynamic beta (8 mApp / 30 uApp) and 200 for the static beta (6 mA / 30 uA)

Comment: Exactly, that's why I didn't want to bother telling him to calculate other than peak-to-peak because it is the easiest value to read and do only simple subtraction and division. Our values may be slightly different because it depends on how precisely we read the curves, but it's there in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

The gain is indeed the BLUE line, and it's marked by the gain equation for a common emitter amplifier Ic(Q1)/Ib(Q1)

I think what's getting you is that it's not a constant value and you are expecting one?   This is just showing that the gain varies with instantaneous operating states.

It's called 'distortion'  ;)

And it's 100% expected in a common-emitter amplifier (without feedback)

Comment: You mean the blue line, not the purple one.

Comment: Yeah, he might have overlooked it.

Comment: Right - Purple  LOL   .  My bad   ;)    FIxed it